# MongoDB gives out of memory at dumping

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodump

I have a database which is almost 4gb size which working on 16GB memory, 6 core Ubuntu 18.04. I write a cron which backup database at specific time everyday, but yesterday, firstly it occured an error which is `Out of memory` at backup process and killed the mongo service. This is my script for dumping `mongodump --db $DB --archive=/home/backup/$BACKUP_NAME --gzip`. I am not sure 4gb is big for a db, so what do you suggest for me ?

Comment: How much memory was the backup process actually using?

Comment: How can i find that value, is there a default value or can it change according ram usage that time ? However, I can say that mongoDB was using 15 GB memory usage in normal time, my total RAM capacity is 16GB.

Comment: You can use `top` or `ps` while dumping.